# Run a XNA compiled game from DVD or CD on XBOX 360?

Tags: xna, xbox360

Is it possible to run a XNA game compiled for XBOX 360 from a DVD or CD, or does it have to be copied onto the HD?

Is it possible to include a library which is not a part of the .net compact framework in a XBOX 360 project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XNA games must be copied to the 360 using the XNA game launcher. They can not be loaded off  a CD/DVD.

You can use other libraries on the 360, but they have to be compiled using the XBox's .net libraries. So unless you have access to source code, or are willing to decompile and change all references to framework libraries to Xbox ones and then remove any calls which don't exist on the 360, you shouldn't try.